# Каким методом можно заменить слово между скобками на toUpperCase() js

Tags: javascript

что бы при вводе: как "было"
выдавало: как БЫЛО
каким методом для строки можно указывать 1 и 2 значение(скобка и скобка ) и чтобы между ними оно изменяло toUpperCase();

Comment: изменить строку между 2 значениями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\([^)]*\)/, (s) => s.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: можешь плз исправить function ddd(params) {
    str.replace(/\([^)]*\)/, (s) => s.toUpperCase());
    return str;
};
var str = "жили 'ffff'";
console.log(ddd(s));

Comment: fff не UpperCase все равно выводит маленьким

Comment: function ddd(str) { return str.replace(/'[^']*'/, (s) => s.toUpperCase()); };
var str = "жили 'ffff'";
console.log(ddd(str));

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: а где можно почитать про эти символы /<[^']*/

Comment: а точнее что значит ^

Comment: https://javascript.ru/regexp